# Proof that a constraints set is closed

Tags: general-topology, functions, optimization, continuity, constraints

I would be grateful if someone is willing to check my solution to the following problem:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, two orthogonal vectors $\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{d} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbf{c} \neq 0, \mathbf{d} \neq 0$ .

Define the function $\psi: \mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by:
$$
\psi(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}-\langle\mathbf{d}, \mathbf{x}\rangle, \quad \forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} .
$$

Prove that the following set is closed:
$$
\left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} ;\langle\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{x}\rangle=0, \text { and } \psi(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0\right\}\\
$$

**My attempt:**

Writing the terms explicitly and making a "merge" of both conditions:
$$
\left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} ;\psi(\mathbf{x}) \leq \langle\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{x}\rangle\right\}\\=
\left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} ; \|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}-\langle\mathbf{d}, \mathbf{x}\rangle \leq\langle\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{x}\rangle\right\}\\
=\left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} ;\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}-\langle\mathbf{d}, \mathbf{x}\rangle-\langle\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{x}\rangle \leq 0\right\}
$$

Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
&g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
&x \longmapsto\|\mathbf{x}\|^{2}-\langle\mathbf{d}, \mathbf{x}\rangle-\langle\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{x}\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$

Now $g$ is continuous as the inner product is (and so does the norm which the inner product induces).

Is it possible to say that since the set above is actually $
g^{-1}((-\infty, 0])
$, then it is a preimage of continuous function on a closed set  and hence is closed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set is the intersection of the sets$$\{\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^n\mid\langle\mathbf c,\mathbf x\rangle=0\}\tag1$$and$$\{\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^n\mid\psi(\mathbf x)\leqslant0\}.\tag2$$All you need to do then is to prove that both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are closed sets. But if $\varphi\colon\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is the function defined by $\varphi(\mathbf x)=\langle\mathbf c,\mathbf x\rangle$, then$$(1)=\varphi^{-1}\bigl(\{0\}\bigr)\quad\text{and}\quad(2)=\psi^{-1}\bigl(]-\infty,0]\bigr).$$So, since $\varphi$ and $psi$ are continuous and $\{0\}$ and $]-\infty,0]$ are closed subsets of $\Bbb R$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are indeed continuous.

Concerning your attempt, I see no reason why your equalities between sets would hold.